# Javascript for programming Photoshop commands

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

Are there any tutorials available for creating Photoshop commands written in Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.rags-int-inc.com/PhotoTechStuff/PscsScripts/

or you can go right to the source...
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_javascript_ref.pdf